# Configure an IIS 10 ASP.NET MVC app to allow only specific domain user to access "/api/" URLs

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

This is on Windows Server 2019, the web app is a ASP.NET MVC app (.NET FW 4.6)

I'm not sure how to debug this.

- **The AppPool runs under a Managed Service Account!** (not that it helps using AppPoolIdentity :-| )
- I've enabled/installed Windows and URL Authentication (disabled all else)
- I can access all other urls, but not the API ones when I add the below
- Server and client are in the same domain (MYDOMAIN)
- Getting the same response from any web browser (We have Windows auth working on a ASP.NET Core on another server from the same browser, but that is for the entire site, not just part of it)
- NTLM provider is used, kernel mode and extended protection turned off

The config looks like this:

```
  <location path="API">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="MYDOMAIN\username" />
        <deny users="*" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The app has it's own login (forms) but I need to use windows login just to restrict API access:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="180" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

We'd really like to avoid any coding here, just config, if possible.

Comment: Just enable basic auth?

Comment: @bjoster Can't test right now but doesn't that require one to enter user/pwd in a dialog?